# Dynamically change the contents of a TableRow within a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tablelayout

Is it possible to dynamically change the contents of a TableRow within a TableLayout?

Currently, I have a simple table layout, something like this:

```
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <TableRow>   
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/tv1text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/tv2text" />   

        </TableRow>

        <!-- more TableRows ... -->

    </TableLayout>
```

What I want to do is dynamically change the TextView of the second column with another view (in my case, an EditView).  The reason for this is that I want the table to present data in a read-only mode first, and then switch to an editable state, say after the user presses an Edit button.

Is this possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. It will be a pain, though. You will have to inflate your XML and then, upon receiving the trigger to swap to an EditText you will have you find the id of the view you want to remove, and remove that view. Then you will have to create a new EditText, give it an id and create a new LayoutParams that is similar to the View you are removing. Then add the EditText the to view group.